# Why increasing the sample size increase statistical significance?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

Why increasing the sample size increase statistical significance? How to mathematically show that when we get more samples, the small difference would become statistically significant easier?

Comment: You might want to read about [power analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test). It would be more correct to state that increasing the sample size increases the power of a statistical test. If a null hypothesis is truly correct then nothing changes in the probability of rejecting the hypothesis.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279162/unbiased-hypothesis-test-what-does-it-mean-actually/279199#279199. Although the plot in the answer is about the "left tail", the "right tail" provides an illustration regarding your question.

Comment: Another example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374031/help-calculating-the-power-function-at-a-point-mu-0-5-for-the-normal-distribu